# What explains the ending of Triple 9?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, triple-9

The ending of *Triple 9* doesn't make much sense.

Why would a police sergeant (Jeffrey) who was investigating the bank robbery case for the whole time (which suggests he could not be one of the corrupt cops), would want to kill detective Franco at the end without any apparent reason?

Answer (score 2):

Because he knew officer Rodriguez was the 4th from the heist and was planning to kill his nephew, officer Chris Allen for the 999 to give them time to pull off the second job but that only pissed him off and showed him what type of person Rodriguez was but the main reason was that he knew Rodriguez was cleaning up after himself and was going to kill his nephew Chris Allen to leave nobody that could lead back to him.